# In Ruby, how can I update the avatar / background image file.jpg in a folder?

Tags: ruby, twitter, directory, jpeg, avatar

My image files are in a folder titled "avis" and each jpeg file inside has a title of "IMG_36754.JPG". The numbers are kind of random. My problem is that I can't get the client to update the avatar or the background image.

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key        = "xxxxx"
    config.consumer_secret     = "xxxxx"
    config.access_token        = "xxxxx"
    config.access_token_secret = "xxxxx"
end
```

When I try the code below, I get an error that reads " No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - IMG_7394.JPG (Errno::ENOENT)"

```
file5 = File.open(Dir.entries("avis").sample)

puts client.update_profile_image(file5)
```

When I use this code below, I get an error "No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - avi (Errno::ENOENT)"

```
avis = Dir.entries("avis")

avi = avis.sample.to_s


file = File.read("avi","r")
puts client.update_profile_image(file)
```

I tried to make it so that it can get the image file from the folder and then have the update profile method use the image string to update, however it doesn't seem to work. please help, thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that file paths are relative from the directory you execute the rubyscript from. WIthout seeing your folder structure I can't tell you exactly what is wrong. Use irb, and try various file commands to figure out the correct string paths you need.

Comment: irb? I use terminal and sublime with ruby... @agmcleod , but I guess I'll write out the paths...can you give me an example of where to type the paths and to open?

Comment: If you use terminal, just type `irb`. You then have an interactive ruby prompt. Can press ctrl+c to exit any time. Just a nice way to test little methods or try different things quickly without editing a file. For example, if i type `irb` and run `Dir['**/*']`, i'll see all files and folders available. From this you can probably deduce the string you need to resolve your images.

Comment: oh ok cool. so if i use a file open and the correct path to the folder I should be ok then? @agmcleod  ...i'll try that in irb